# New to Lilypond, I want a guitar chord box above each bar of the staff , does anyone have a template?

Tags: guitar, jazz, lilypond

I am new to Lilypond, I want to print blank  guitar chord box(es) above each of the 32 bars of the blank staff , does anyone have a template?

Answer (score 3):

Maybe something like this:

```
\version "2.20.0"
\header {tagline = ##f}
\paper {page-count = 1
  ragged-last-bottom = ##f}
fourBarsThenBreak = {
        \repeat unfold 4 {s1^\markup {
              \fret-diagram #"d:0;6-1;5-1;4-1;3-1;2-1;1-1;"
             }        
        }\break
  }

global = {
  \key c \major
  \time 4/4
}

classicalGuitar = \relative c' {
  \global
   \repeat unfold 8 {\fourBarsThenBreak} \bar "|."
}

\score {
  \new Staff = "Classical guitar"
  { \clef "treble_8" \classicalGuitar }
  \layout { }
}
```

In `\fret-diagram #"d:0...` `d` is diameter of dots for finger placement. So setting diameter to `0` seems to be the way.